AWS Enable pipeline step based on the result of the last one
I am adding the following step to AWS CodePipeline and it is running on every execution ; but I want enable/disable as per the result of STEP 1 pipeline. Is there a way I can do the same.
STEP 2 = codebuild.PipelineProject(
            scope=self,
            id="1",
            description="DESCRIPTION",
            project_name=f"{self.stack_name}-project-1",
            build_spec=<details added here>,
            environment=codebuild.BuildEnvironment(
                privileged=True,
                build_image=codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.from_code_build_image_id(
                    "aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:5.0"
                ),
            ),
            encryption_key=artifacts_kms_key,
            queued_timeout=Duration.minutes(15),
            role=<role>,
            timeout=Duration.minutes(30),
            vpc=vpc,
            environment_variables={
                "AWS_ACCOUNT_ID": <value entered here>
            },
        )


